# Taylor Series with a Derivative

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

The question asks for a Taylor Series for $f'(x)$. Although my answers keep resulting in problems because of the subtraction of the $x$. Tried to find a similar problem on the internet and textbook examples, but to no avail.

$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin(x) - x}{x^{2}}
$$

My work:

$$ f(x) = a(x) + b(x) $$

where:

$$ a(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{2}} $$ 
$$ b(x) = \frac{1}{x} $$

From there, $a(x)$ is doable (I believe), but $b(x)$ is not. I tried taking the integral of $b(x)$, but $\ln(x)$ does not have a Taylor Series polynomial either (obviously). I was going to try and break it up and find the taylor series for $f(x)$ and then take the derivative of that. I am most definitely looking at this problem the wrong way.

Comment: You're right that you're not looking at the problem the right way -- your approach effectively says that the limit as $n \to \infty$ of 0 does not exist because $0 = n - n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} n = \infty$ and $\infty-\infty$ doesn't make sense. In this case, it is crucial that you consider the quotient as a whole. First find the Taylor series for $f(x)$ about 0 (after filling in $f(0)$ with $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$); here it will help to first plug in the series for $\sin x$. Then differentiate the series -- recall that the power series of a derivative is the derivative of the power series.

Comment: Taking the derivative and then doing the Taylor series is equivalent to doing the Taylor series and then taking the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know by heart (or you can obtain) the Taylor series of the $\sin$:
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$$
Then:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin x-x}{x^2} =-\frac{x}{3!}+\frac{x^3}{5!}+\cdots$$
so the derivative is:
$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{3!}+3\,\frac{x^2}{5!}+\cdots$$
If you wish, you can guess a "nice" general formula:
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+3)!}$$

Comment: I was complicating the question way too much. Thanks for all the help